# How to include different classes with same name?

Tags: php, class, oop

Here is the problem, I have a script `test.php` there is a loop inside it in this loop I want to use 4 classes (separate files) from different folders (they are pdf print classes, but everyone is different by the others), all of them are with same names `PdfCreator` I want every iteration to include/require (use) different class:

```
$brokerTables = ['test1' => 'broker_report', 'test2' => 'choice_report', 'test3' => 'odit_report', 'test4' => 'other_insurer_report'];

foreach ($brokerTables as $folder => $table) {

    require_once($folder . '/classes/' . $brokerTables[$folder]);

    $pdfdoc = new PdfCreator($this->conn);

    // use $pdfdoc..

};
```

Is there a way to do it ? without rename of classes ?

Error is **Cannot declare class PdfCreator, because the name is already in use**

Comment: I would say that NameSpaces would solve this, but honestly I am not completely sure what the question is

Comment: @RiggsFolly Namespaces would be one way to come up with unique names, but they're not actually necessary; the code looks much the same if you just call the classes `A_PdfCreator`, `B_PdfCreator`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental answer is that you can't. Class names in PHP are unique, and outside of some exotic extension that should never be used in production, cannot be "undeclared" or renamed.

So, you'll need to come up with a different program design. For instance, you could use the folder name as part of the class name, or more logically as [a namespace](https://www.php.net/namespace), so that each name is unique. You'll then need to define the class name dynamically to create the object, like this:

```php
$className = "\\MyTopLevelNamespace\\{$folder}\\PdfCreator";
$pdfdoc = new $className($this->conn);
```

Note that namespaces aren't necessary here, you can use any naming scheme you like, to make the class names unique, e.g.

```php
$className = "{$folder}_PdfCreator";
$pdfdoc = new $className($this->conn);
```

An additional advantage of using the folder somewhere in the class name or namespace is that you can use [an autoloader](https://www.php.net/autoload) to find the definition, rather than explicitly writing the `require_once` statement each time you need the class.